# How to interpret mathematical negation in terms of logic

Tags: logic

An example of negation which is meant specifically for the question.

> *Statement:* (∀x∈N)(∃y∈N)(x+y = 1), *Negative:* (∃x∈N)(∀y∈N)(x+y≠1)

A real life implication

> *Statement:* For every hour, there is a man who dies, *Negative:* There exists an hour in which all men don't die

---

How do we interpret the mentioned example in the means of logic? I thought that the following negation is enough to conclude the right negative meaning of the statement

> There exists an hour in which a man doesn't die

So what's the point in terms of logic to negate

> A man

to

> All men

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to negate the statement, "For every hour, there is a man who dies."

Let's see intuitively when this statement is true.  This statement should be true if, **at any given hour**, you can find a man who dies.

So, when is it false then?  Well, it's **definitely** false if you can find a single hour such that **no man** dies during that hour.  Right?  But if **no man dies**, that means **every man lives**.

So it's not enough to find an hour such that a single man lives.  There could still be another man somewhere else who has died.

Comment: Totally appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Some man not dying is not the negation of some man dying, for both can be true at the same time.

So rather: if it is not true that some man dies, then it is true for *all* men that they do not die.

Comment: Thank you, That was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The statement "For every hour, there is a man who dies" is saying $$\forall h\,\exists m\, D(m, h)$$ where $D(x,y)$ means man $x$ died in hour $y$.

The negation of this statement is clearly $\exists h\,\forall m\, \lnot D(m,h)$.

Translating back to English, we have: there is an hour in which *no* man dies, i.e. *all* men don't die.

Answer (score 0):

> *Statement:* For every hour, there is a man who dies.

$$\forall x:[H(x) \implies \exists y:[M(y) \land D(y,x)]]$$

where

- $H(x)$ means $x$ is an hour in time
- $M(y)$ means $y$ is a man
- $D(y,x)$ means $y$ dies in $x$

> *Negative:* There exists an hour in which all men don't die

$$\exists x:[H(x) \land \forall y:[M(y) \implies \neg D(y,x)]]$$

*Hint:* Makes use of quantifier switching, the definition of implication and the removing of double negations.

Comment: @Thomas I was quoting the OP.

Answer (score 0):

$∀x.P(x)=true$ means "for every $x$, $P(x)$ is true".

We know that it is negation is "There is at least one $x$ such that $P(x)$ is false". It is symbollically written as $∃x.P(x)=false$.

This is a similar idea with if you want support a statement, you prove it for all $x$, or if you disagree you prove it by giving a (at least one) counter-example.

So this is how ∀ and ∃ end up being inverse of each other.